# После diskpart clean флэшка не отображается в списке дисков

Tags: windows, диск, diskpart

Я отформатировал флэш-накопитель при помощи команды `clean` из утилиты `diskpart`. Теперь флэшка пуста, но она не отображается в окне "Компьютер" в списке дисков. Совсем. Компьютер реагирует на её подключение, но новых дисков не появляется.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы накопитель появился в этом списке и вообще функционировал как самая обычная флэшка?

Comment: @Иван, нормально написанный вопрос ценнее тысячи извинений ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Возвращайтесь в `diskpart`, выберите этот же диск и выполните следующее так же, как выполнили на нём `clean`:

```
create partition primary
```

---

#### А что это было?

Каждый диск можно разбить на некоторое число разделов, на каждом из которых будет своя файловая система. Изначально, скорее всего, на вашей флэшке был один раздел на всю ширь диска. Командой `clean` вы его уничтожили.

Поскольку форматировать (т. е. создавать файловую систему) можно только в рамках раздела, Проводник с этой флэшкой сделать ничего не сможет, пока вы не создадите там раздел.

[У команды `create partition primary` есть некоторые параметры](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx), но они все необязательны, при их отсутствии утилита попытается создать раздел максимально возможного размера от самого начала диска.

В следующий раз, если будете стирать флэшку, отформатируйте её из контекстного меню Проводника. Вы забрались глубже, чем требовалось. Кстати, после создания раздела диск как раз надо будет отформатировать, поскольку файловой системы там не будет.